# C++ How to store information inside a object pointer vector?

Tags: c++, object

Let's say I have two member variables called attribute name and value and I want to store them inside a vector called attributes. I know I can create an object so let's say I had a class called Element and then I created an object called `Element* Element_object` Now I want to store the attribute name and attribute value inside of Element_object vector. I know there's a function called push_back() that helps you to do so. I was thinking that I would something like this `attributes.push_back(attribute_value);`except that won;t work because attribute is type element pointer and attribute value is a string type. Should I change the type of my vector attribute from element* to a string and then do `attributes.push_back(attribute_value);`I want to store multiple attributes inside the object vector so I'm assuming that in order to store multiple attributes inside element_object vector I would keep using push_back()?

My .h file looks like this:

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h

#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>  
#include <string>   
#include <vector>   
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Element{
public:
 void set_attribute_name(string temp_attribute_name);
 string get_attribute_name();
 void set_attribute_value(string temp_attribute_value);
 string get_attribute_value();
private:
    /**Member variables**/
    vector<Element*> attributes;
    string attribute_name;
    string attribute_value;
};

#endif /* Header_h */
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Does an Element have attributes, as well as it contains other elements, which in turn has their respective attributes. Does each element only have one attribute name/value pair? I would suggest you model your interface from a call perspective, then we can start thinking about how to implement. Therefore, how do you plan to call an element. How do you plan to set it's attribute/s. Does it only have one attribute. How do you want to use it. This is not clear from your question. Once this is clear, the solution will become too.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a separate class or a simple struct will do.
you cannot push individual struct members to vector. you need to push the entire object/pointer to obj.

```
struct keyvalue
{
  std::string attribute_name;
  std::string attribute_value;
};

vector<keyvalue*> vecKeyValue;

in implementation file:


keyvalue* pkval = new(std::nothrow) keyvalue;

pkval->attribute_name = "name";
pkval->attribute_value = "value";

vecKeyValue.push_back(pkval);
```